# Jquery mobile php site and phonegap

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, cordova

I was trying to convert my website which ceated using jquery and its contain a few `PHP` page into Android application by using phonegap online converting tool, the app work on navigation but the `PHP` page will not work accordingly, so is there any way to work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run php scripts on a mobile phone, you can convert all php scripts to html pages or you could load the whole website inside the webview.

place `window.location = 'example.com'` inside your deviceLoad event and make sure you whitelisted your website in your config.xml

What to place inside the config.xml can be found here.
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

However, you need an internet connection to run the app, while the html pages doesn't require internet.

Comment: So do i need code it to enable internet connection inorder to make this app to work?

Comment: No, android will take care of the connection itself. You can make a develop website

Comment: oh alright but if i developed the website not using Eclipise but just other IDE such as Notepad++ it will ve same patter as that Tutorial showed above right?
And do i only need to change the page that contain php code, html page can still remain the same?